# Redirect subdomain to another subdomain same structure subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I am tying to redirect subdomain

```
http://subdomain.example.com/path/to/directory/orfile.ext
```

to same structure but different domain extension

```
http://subdomain.example.net/path/to/directory/orfile.ext
```

Additional Question

1- Is that possible to have a code that redirect all wildcard in the site if i have subdomain1 sundomain 2?

2- Where Exactly should i put the .htaccess code ? in the www directory or inside each subfolder directory ?

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

this code write in .htaccess file and put on the root folder of old domain (your domain1)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: it redirect the main website but not the subdomains

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**1.** Copy this code:

```
  Redirect 301 / http://subdomain.to-go-to.net/
```

into a file called `.htaccess`

this will redirect all urls e.g. with their segments e.g.

```
http://subdomain.example.NET/user/login/whatever
```

will become

```
http://subdomain.example.COM/user/login/whatever
```

**2.** Place the `.htaccess` file into the root directory of the old site - it wont work if you put it in subdirectories

Comment: this code redirect all links to the main link only , not the same structure of the URL like i explained in my main question

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://%1example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect all the requests (including requests to **all the subdomains**) for your `example.com` domain to `example.net` with the same path structure.

Place this in your document `root` directory of the example.`com` site.

**Note:**

If you want to redirect only the subdomains (not the main domain), have this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://%1\.example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: this one redirect but when i redirect test.example.com it redirect to test.example.com/test it should reciredt without the test folder so it should be test.example.com

Comment: `test.example.com` should redirect to `test.example.net`. Please retest after clearing the browser cache.

Comment: unfortunately it still redirect to test.example.com/test it should not redirect without test subfolder of the subdomain , there is no other .htaccess inside the subfolder test only this code in the main website directory folder www

Comment: kumas wait i will re-check again my other browser and i will update my post shortly

Comment: i tried but still the same on all other browsers , opera , firefox , ie , i don't know what cause the redirect make the subdomain name repeat twice in the URl test.example.com/test . it should be redirect test.exacmple.com/test

Comment: note: that the main website in the www directory , and the subdomains are folders inside www like if there is test.example.com , you will see a test folder inside www folder which is the main folder. and the .htaccess located only in the main www direcoty not the subdomains folders